# What does "in progress" mean in this Olympic schedule image?

Tags: meaning

What does "in progress" mean in this Olympic schedule image?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post, provide your research on the matter and include a specific concern that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When discussing schedules, "in progress" means that something is happening now.

In your example, they're saying that "women's beam" is scheduled to start at 9:46 pm, a time that presumably had not yet arrived when this schedule was posted. But "women's 200m" has already started.

Answer (score -1):

It means that the competion has been started but is not yet finished. In other words, they are currently running/swimming.